# A Silverlight application with .net Ria services and SilverlightFX

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, mvvm, wcf-ria-services, silverlight.fx

I am starting to write an application in Silverlight with RIA services and SilverlightFx.
 Now this application is a pretty big one has has lot of interaction between controls.

As an estimate it will have around 60-70 user controls. Now my questions are..

1. Is it good to choose .Net Ria and SilverlightFx? (My view is..It is not going to production very soon. And as it is a big one using frameworks will help unit testing and save development time once the frameworks are understood properly.)
2. After reading through the blogs I am not really clear how SilverlightFx handles interaction between user controls. For example I have a user control (say "S") that have the search functionality...auto complete and all...Now I have another UserControl (Say "R") that displays the search results. The display result panel can be used from search user control or another user control (Say F) that gives all items of a particular category. I can not marge Search and Select Category into a single userontrol. So how to do it?
   If I create different ViewModels how they will interect with each other?
3. Is it better to create Domain service context in each ViewModel or to use a single one across the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note to preface answer - I am the author of Silverlight.FX, and architect for RIA Services ... so factor in bias in the reply :-) ...

I did two blog posts on the combination of the two you might find helpful: [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern.aspx) and [here](http://www.nikhilk.net/NET-RIA-Services-ViewModel-Pattern-2.aspx). These cover basic view model scenarios using a DomainContext and basic unit testing of view models using the Silverlight Unit Test Framework.

Silverlight.FX offers more than just graphical interaction. From the site (http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX):

- Application Model - SilverlightFX
  features a richer Application object
  providing a service model, an IoC
  container, support for theming, view
  model (M-V-VM), navigation and MVC,
  amongst various other features.
- User Interface Components - SilverlightFX
  provides a small set of enhanced
  controls, support for Forms and
  Windows, master page like containers,
  layout controls and data-bound
  controls.
- Declarative Views -
  SilverlightFX provides a framework
  for writing behaviors, actions,
  triggers, and commands, and also
  provides a set of out-of-the-box
  implementations.
- Effects and
  Transitions - SilverlightFX provides
  a procedural animation framework
  capable of implementing tweens and
  interpolations and easing behaviors.
  Additionally it provides simple but
  broadly applicable animations that
  can be applied as effects and
  transitions to standard controls in a
  fully declarative manner.

The way to handle the notifications across view models would be to use some sort of event aggregator pattern that allows view models to publish and subscribe to events in a decoupled manner.

This feature isn't yet in Silverlight.FX, but is slated to go in hopefully soon. I demonstrated this sort of communication recently in my TechEd South Africa talk - check out the slides and code for an implementation of this: http://www.nikhilk.net/TechEd09-South-Africa-Samples.aspx.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there, first off i dont know if SLFX provides any useful features besides graphical interaction, i suggest you take a look at [prism](http://codeplex.com/prism) for proper MVVM integration and proper use of Regions in your design, and then communication between regions (simply speaking, usercontrols but a little more dynamic in its loading)

1. Unit testing from SL3 interface
   means that you must have a means to
   simulate user input, there are quite
   a few ways todo this. One of the
   easiest is the MVVM approach and
   thereby simulating input into the
   viewmodel. prism support for SL3
   will co-incide with the release of
   WPF 4.0. prism currently does
   support SL3 just not the navigation
   framework, as it clashes alot with
   prism's region navigation, but they
   perform different tasks and they
   dont overlap functionality.

   2. If you have usercontrols "S", and "R" then, they both will share a
      common datasource, being the
      viewmodel, therefore properties
      within the viewmodel can communicate
      with each other, this mostly happens
      when the OnPropertyChanged event is
      fired. or a button is clicked, then
      using prism's commanding, you can
      hookup a button control click method
      to a method in the viewmodel.
   3. It really depends on alot of things, such as concurrency, since
      all calls from SL3 are async,
      meaning you can shoot of 3 queries
      at once over the same domain
      context, and how many connections
      you want created to your WCF
      service. i havent used RIA enough to
      understand the implications of the
      choices you have, so i cant give you
      an exact answer, but the general
      rule is to keep db connections to a
      minimum (Domain context recycling
      does not automatically convert into
      less connections since WCF is
      stateless unless otherwise designed)

Comment: Are you telling to keep same ViewModel class for both "S" and "R" then again how usercontrol "F" will ommunicate with it? Or is it better to change my viewmodel such that both "S" "R" and "F" shares the same view model.

Comment: If you have 4 controls on a single view(page), then all four controls share the same viewmodel, each view will have its own viewmodel, each view consists of multiple controls. the prism way of doing things is having regions within a single view(page) and each region has its own viewmodel, and then there is a mechanism to allow regions to communicate. 
if S, R, F and tightly coupled on a single view, then they should share the same viewmodel, theres no point in decoupling the viewmodels when the view explicity depends on them being tightly coupled.

Comment: ViewModels are specific to a view, and Models are specific to a ViewModel, this also works backwards.
if you want a different ViewModel on each control, then i suggest you go the region route it makes more sense for your problem, but thats the point are you ever going to swap the implementation of a single control?